# Cloud Function to copy file to another bucket. Memory limit of 2048 MiB exceeded with 2050 MiB used. Consider increasing the memory limit,

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing a cloud function to copy files from source bucket to another buckets with different projects. The number of files in source bucket will be created around 500,000 files daily.

I get this error several times.

> Memory limit of 2048 MiB exceeded with 2050 MiB used. Consider
> increasing the memory limit, see
> https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/memory

What is the problems and how to solve this error?

Info:

```
Trigger Type: Cloud Storage 
Event: finalizing/creating
Memory Allocate: 2 GB
timeout: 540
Maximum number of instance: 500
```

```py
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage import Blob
from datetime import date, datetime,timedelta
def handle(event, context):
        try:
            file = event
            file_name = file['name']
            trigger_time = file['timeCreated']
            file_extention = file_name.split('/')[-1]
            plat_form = file_name.split('/')[1]
            is_jsondata = file_name.split('/')[3]
            device_id = file_name.split('/')[2]
            #active_date = datetime.now()+ timedelta(days=-1)
            active_date = trigger_time[0:10]
            print(f"trigger time is {active_date}")
            if plat_form == 'android' and is_jsondata == 'jsonData' and file_extention[0:10] == active_date:
                print(f"Processing Step1 {file_extention}  and {file_extention[0:10]}")
                print(f"Processing File: {file['name']}.")
                storage_client = storage.Client(project='bucketA')
                #storage_client = storage.Client(project='bucketA')
                #storage_client_des = storage.Client(project='data-ingestion-production')
                source_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucketa.appspot.com')
                #source_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucketA.appspot.com')
                destination_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucketb_tmp')
                #destination_object_name = storage_client.get_object('mobileDataSDK_dev/')
                prefix = 'movile/android/'
                blobs = list(source_bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix))
                #target_name = file_name.split('/')[-1]
                #target_path = 'mobileDataSDK_dev/'+active_date.strftime("%Y%m%d")+'/'+device_id+'/'
                target_path = 'movile/android/'+active_date+ '/'+device_id+'/'
                for blob in blobs:
                    if blob.name == file_name:
                        source_blob = source_bucket.blob(blob.name)
                        destination_path = target_path+file_extention
                        #destination_path = target_path+blob.name
                        new_blob = source_bucket.copy_blob(
                        source_blob, destination_bucket, destination_path    
                        )
                        print(f"File move from {source_blob} to {new_blob}")
    
            else:
                print("Don't match criteria")
                
        except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
            print("Some errors")
            pass
```

Comment: How many blobs does the bucket contain? The `list(source_bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix))` is likely the problem if you have a very large amount of blobs. You should probably use the returned iterator directly, instead of materializing all of the blob information objects at once into the list. The iterator retrieves them in pages (AFAIK). Also, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/buckets#class-googlecloudstoragebucketbucketclient-namenone-userprojectnone) specifies that `list_blobs` is deprecated and you should use `Client.list_blobs` instead.

Comment: Hi!  Is your CF triggering off a finalize or delete?  Assuming that's the case, you don't have to do a list at all.  You can just act on the file that triggered the CF in the first place with `.blob(event['name']) `

Comment: Hi,  Mark Rotteveel and Glen Yu. Thank you so much for your help. Already solve it with your suggestion.